# How to use Content Complete Module?

Tags: views, blocks, 7

Tried to read https://www.drupal.org/project/content_complete but that didn't give me much so now I'm stuck.

I've set what Content Type + Fields to use and Rebuilt Cache. Then I keep getting this error "You need to provide a completeness data field in the display 'Master'." when I try to create a View. Don't know what Master means here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Master display is the 1st Views page that you edit when making a new View. Typically this is a Page or Block in Drupal7. So you have a View somewhere that if you try to save it the View will say you need to supply at least 1 field for the completeness data field. So I suggest going through all of your Views and trying press Save on each 1 (because you dont know which 1 it is apparently or what exactly we're talking about) -- 1 will complain it cannot be saved until you fix this error in it.